# Using a function handle with equation and Simpson's rule

Tags: matlab

I'm working on a problem that applies a luminosity equation:

E = 64.77* T^−4 ∫ x^−5( e^(1.432/Tx) -1 )^−1 dx

Where T = 3500;

to simp son's rule which is a few sums and such.

problem 17.8 here: http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/computer-aided-engineering/9780123748836/-introduction-to-numerical-methods/ch17lev1sec10

---

What I've done is made a function simpson(fn, a, b, h) that runs simp son's rule correctly. 
however, the problem is making that integral equation into a function handle that works. I've gotten it to work for simple function handles like

```
f = @x x.^2
```

but when I try and make the integral into a function:

```
fn = @(x)(64.77/T^4).*integral((x.^(-5)).*((exp(((1.432)./(3500.*x)))).^(-1)), 4e-5, 7e-5);
simp(fn, 5, 15, 1)
 function s = simp(fn, a, b, h)

 x1 = a + 2*h:2*h:b-2*h;
 sum1 = sum(feval(fn, x1));
 x2 = a + h:22*h:b-h;
 sum2 = sum(feval(fn, x2));

 s = h/3*(feval(fn, a) + feval(fn, b) + 4*sum2 + 2*sum1);
```

it doesn't work. error message is Integral: first input must be function handle.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's wrong without looking at your `simp` function source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're supposed to be evaluating the integral using Simpsons rule, whereas you are using `integral` to calculate the integral, then `fn` is not a function of `x`. You want to do this:

```
fn = @(x)(x.^(-5)).*((exp(((1.432)./(3500.*x)))).^(-1));
I=simp(fn,a,b,h);
E=(64.77/T^4)*I;
```